# No X11R6 directory in Cygwin

Tags: windows, cygwin, x11

I am trying to install XFig on my Windows-7 machine using the [this popular blog](http://www.gohappycup.com/personal/latex/xfig.html). In doing so, the steps required me to install Cygwin which I did and I included the X11 package.

The blog then suggests to include `C:\Cygwin\usr\X11R6\bin` into my `PATH` variable but I do not find any such directory in my Cygwin directory. Can someone suggest what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C:\Cygwin\usr\X11R6\bin` or better `/usr/X11R6/bin` is obsolete.
By long time has been replaced by `/usr/bin`

Please note that xfig is already available as cygwin package.
https://cygwin.com/packages/x86_64/xfig/

Just use setup to install it.

Comment: Thanks. When I tried opening xfig from cygwin terminal, it complained that it can't open the display localhost:0

Comment: Because it is a X program. You need to run the X server and run xfig from a X Terminal